# Where are directory specific "rustup overrides" stored?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to get comfortable with the toolchain. I see that there is an option to override the toolchain defaults at a project specific level, by running:

`rustup override set`

I'm trying to figure out where is this configuration maintained.  Also when running `rustup override list` it shows me a mapping (symlinks?) Where does it read this from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `~/.rustup/settings.toml` but I don't see the point to know this. https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup#configuration-files "The schema for this file is not part of the public interface for rustup - the rustup CLI should be used to query and set settings." as expected

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur -- I'm trying to fix another issue related to the Rust VS Code extension and wanted to debug it -- Unfortunately I still can't figure out why and have asked this question on SO now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991370/vs-code-rust-extension-errors